# Ruby Count Smiley Face - Exit Code = 1

Tags: arrays, ruby, exit-code

The count smiley face question on Codewars, my codes passed all the tests, but an "Exit Code = 1" error message keeps popping up, what does that mean? What went wrong?

```
countSmileys([':)', ';(', ';}', ':-D']);       // should return 2;
countSmileys([';D', ':-(', ':-)', ';~)']);     // should return 3;
countSmileys([';]', ':[', ';*', ':$', ';-D']); // should return 1;

    def count_smileys(arr)
      first = ";:"
      second = "-~"
      third = ")D"
      arr.select{|x|
        third.include?(x[1]) or (second.include?(x[1]) && third.include?(x[2].to_s)) 
      }.count
    end
```

**EDIT:**
The error message is as below:

```
main.rb:8:in `include?': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from main.rb:8:in `block in count_smileys'
    from main.rb:7:in `select'
    from main.rb:7:in `count_smileys'
    from main.rb:16:in `block in <main>'
    from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:55:in `block in describe'
    from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:46:in `measure'
    from /runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:51:in `describe'
    from main.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of `countSmileys` calls?

Comment: I just pasted the calls up top when I made the post, when I run the program, the calls are below the actual codes...that's what you meant right?

Comment: No. I meant to change the order of the calls, then look at the exit code you get.

Comment: Please include error message (content of STDERR) in your question.

Comment: An exit code of 1 means that something went wrong. You need to tell us *what* went wrong. What is the error message you are getting? What line does it point to?

Comment: thanks guys, please see my edit

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. There are *many* problems with your code (you call the method before you define it, which cannot possibly work, and you try to call it as `countSmileys`, but you define it as `count_smileys`, and the comment character in Ruby is `#` and not `//`), but apart from *that* your code works perfectly. I get `2`, `3`, and `1`, and no exception.

Comment: I think everything before the `def` is a code sample Codewars provides. That's all javascript not ruby code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what the problem is - there is a test `count_smileys([";", ")", ";*", ":$", "8-D"])` where x[1] and x[2] would not be valid for the first 2 items in the array, so I need to fix the array inside the select method:

```
def count_smileys(arr)
  first = ";:"
  second = "-~"
  third = ")D"
  arr.select{|x|
    x[1] = " " if x[1] == nil
    x[2] = "" if x[2] == nil
    (first.include?(x[0]) && third.include?(x[1])) || (first.include?(x[0]) && second.include?(x[1]) && third.include?(x[2])) 
  }.count
end
```

Joseph Cho was correct in the sense that nils need to be converted, but we should do it in the iteration, and common items x[1] should be set to an empty string with a space to avoid being counted, while x[2] is uncommon enough that an empty string would work.

Answer (score 0):

As the message describes, there's no implicit conversion of nil to string. Explicit does exist though:

```
2.3.1 :001 > nil.to_s
=> ""
```

You could parse your array for `nil` first, and then put it through the `select` method.

```
def count_smileys(arr)
  first = ";:"
  second = "-~"
  third = ")D"

  # parse your array for nil values here
  arr.map {|x| x.nil? ? "" : x }

  arr.select{|x|
    third.include?(x[1]) or (second.include?(x[1]) && third.include?(x[2].to_s)) 
  }.count
end
```